# how do I use vs2008 Performance Wizard

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I can't seem to get started with this tool.

I referenced the article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337887.aspx#S1

but I can't even find the Analyse menu item that it refers to in the article.

I am looking for a walkthrough to get me started on this.

Microsoft Visual Studio 2008
Version 9.0.30729.1 SP
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 3.5 SP1

Installed Edition: Professional

Microsoft Visual Basic 2008   91605-130-0030954-60573
Microsoft Visual Basic 2008

Microsoft Visual C# 2008   91605-130-0030954-60573
Microsoft Visual C# 2008

Microsoft Visual C++ 2008   91605-130-0030954-60573
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008

Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Tools for Office   91605-130-0030954-60573
Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Tools for Office

Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2008   91605-130-0030954-60573
Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2008

Comment: Which version and _edition_ of VS 2008 do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article says:

> In this article, we will show you how
>   you can use **Visual Studio® Team System
>   Development Edition** or **Visual Studio
>   Team Suite** to identify performance
>   bottlenecks in your application.